# Set default document text color except for sections

Tags: color

I want to set a default text colour for the whole document, but I don't want to colour the section headings.

In my case I want all of the default text body with paragraphs etc. to be a very dark shade of grey, while all the section headings remain black (including nested subsections).

I tried this brute-force example, using popular packages, with colours red and blue but it still doesn't work. Everything, including the section heading, is red.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\color{blue}}
\color{red}
\sectionfont{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\section{I should be blue}
\subsection{I should also be blue}
I should be red
\end{document}
```

Comment: Code works OK for me.

Comment: @Cicada My bad the example wasn't general enough. This should work for all sections and sub...subsections, but it doesn't!

Comment: For subsections, you need `\subsectionfont`.

Comment: @Cicada okay but what about subsubsections and subsubsubsections? Isn't there a catch-all command for all nested levels of sections?

Comment: I don't know - I haven't read the manual yet. Don't forget chapters and parts, and paragraphs etc.

Comment: The command is `\allsectionsfont{..}` (manual, p2).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `fontspec` package, the colour can be set as an attribute of the font:

[image: colour]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[Colour=red]
\newfontfamily\ffontb{Noto Serif}[Colour=blue]
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\ffontb}
\subsectionfont{\ffontb}

\begin{document}
\section{I should be blue}
I should be red
\subsection{I should be blue}
\end{document}
```

---

Added:

The `\allsectionsfont` command does all heading levels.

[image: all sections]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}[Colour=red]
\newfontfamily\ffontb{Noto Serif}[Colour=blue]
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\sectionfont{\ffontb}
%\subsectionfont{\ffontb}
\allsectionsfont{\ffontb}


\begin{document}
\section{I should be blue}
I should be red
\subsection{I should be blue}
\part{part}
\chapter{chapter} x x x x x x x x x x x
\section{section} x x x x x x x x x x x
\subsection{subsection} x x x x x x x x x x x
\subsubsection{subsubsection} x x x x x x x x x x x
\paragraph{paragraph} x x x x x x x x x x x
\subparagraph{subparagraph} x x x x x x x x x x x
\end{document}
```